# (SPO) Subsite language template ignored

Tags: sharepoint-server, sub-site, language

EDIT: apllies to Sharepoint Online.

I have site collection based on the italian template.
If I create a subsite and explicitly select the italian template, the subsite will turn out to be using English as the default language anyway.

What's the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I have done a test in my SharePoint 2013 and i cannot reproduce your issue, i have site collection based on the Chinese template. If I create a sub site and select the English template, the sub site will use English as the default language.

If alternative languages are set up by the site collection administrator, then you can create subsites in languages other than the default language.

Create a new subsite in a different language for your reference:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-new-subsite-in-a-different-language-28361bf2-1bb6-4c73-9ee8-4cb966031cf3

Comment: in the site collection: { locale settings: italian, default language: italian, alternate languages: english }. Still, everything is displayed in english. The subsite default becomes English

Comment: does your subsite use the chinese template if you select that one?